# Calculating the limit (L'Hopital)

Tags: calculus, limits

Could you please help me find this limit using L'hospital?
$$
\underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_1^x \frac{t^2}{t + \lvert \sin t \rvert} dt
$$
Thank you!

Comment: My apologies, it is x, not t

Comment: Don't you know how to differentiate integrals?

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We let 
$$
f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}
$$
where
$$
g(x) = \int_1^x \frac{t^2}{t + \lvert \sin t \rvert} dt, \quad h(x) = x^2
$$
As these both tend to infinity as $x\rightarrow \infty$ we can try to compute the limit using L'hospital
$$
\underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} f(x) = \underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{g'(x)}{h'(x)}
$$
Computing $h'(x) = 2x$ is relatively easy and we can compute $g'(x)$ using the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) (FTC)
$$
g'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_1^x \frac{t^2}{t + \lvert \sin t \rvert} dt = \frac{x^2}{x + \lvert \sin x \rvert}.
$$
While the absolute value of the sine makes it so the integrand is not differentiable, recall that the FTC requires only that the integrand be continuous. It does not require that the integrand is differentiable. As our function is, in fact, continuous we can safely apply the FTC. We insert these results into our original limit
$$
\underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} f(x) = \underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{x^2}{x + \lvert \sin x \rvert} \frac{1}{2x} = \underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{x + \lvert \sin x \rvert}
$$
which we can factorize 
$$
\underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{x}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x}\lvert \sin x \rvert} = \underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x}\lvert \sin x \rvert}
$$
Now while the absolute value of $\lvert \sin x \rvert$ may be intimidating, we can evaluate the limit without transforming this in any way. Instead we can apply appropriate bounds. We use that 
$$
0 \leq \lvert \sin x \rvert \leq 1 \quad \forall x
$$
such that the expression
$$
\overbrace{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x} \cdot 1}}^{\text{lower bound}} \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}\lvert\sin x\rvert} \leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x} \cdot 0} \leq \overbrace{\frac{1}{2}}^{\text{upper bound}}
$$
so that when we choose $x$ to be large, we are squeezing the value of $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}\lvert\sin x\rvert}$ between the lower bound and the upper bound. Letting now $x$ go to infinity we calculate the limit value of the lower bound as
$$
\underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
which means our limit value is squeezed by $\frac{1}{2}$ on both sides. In other words the limit
$$
\frac{1}{2} \leq \underset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x}\lvert \sin x \rvert} \leq \frac{1}{2}
$$
and must therefore be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: My apologies, the upper bound of the integral is x, does this change anything?

Comment: No it doesn't change anything. It should have been an x all along but it was a typo. I fixed it now!

Comment: Just another question, I thought we would need to break the absolute value? Or we don't at all?

Comment: We don't need to do that as the term 
$$
\frac{1}{x} \lvert \sin x \rvert \leq \frac{1}{x} \cdot 1
$$
can become as small as we want by choosing $x$ sufficiently large.  Two seconds I'll add to my answer to shine a light on this.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

For all $x \gt 1$ and $t \in [1,x],$ it holds, that
$$
t=\frac{t^2}{t} \ge \frac{t^2}{t+|sin(t)|} \ge \frac{t^2}{t+1} =
\frac{t^2+t-t}{t+1} = \frac{t(t+1)}{t+1} -\frac{t}{t+1} \ge t -1,
$$
which implies
$$ 
\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{1}^{x} t\,dt \ge \frac{1}{x^2}\int_{1}^{x} \frac{t^2}{t+|sin(t)|} \ge \frac{1}{x^2}\int_{1}^{x} (t-1)dt.
$$
Since 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\int_{1}^{x} t\,dt = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\biggl(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac {1}{2}\biggr)=\frac{1}{2}
$$ 
and 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\int_{1}^{x} (t-1)dt= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\biggl(\frac{x^2}{2}-x-\frac{1}{2}+1\biggr)= \lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}\biggr) = \frac{1}{2},
$$
it follows by the squeeze theorem, that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\int_{1}^{x} \frac{t^2}{t+|sin(t)|}dt = 1/2.
$$

Comment: I didn't see by the time I posted, that you wanted us to use l'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: It's all good, please don't worry. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with l'Hopital's Rule:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\int_1^x \frac{t^2}{t+|\sin t|}}{x^2}
&=&
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{x^2}{x+|\sin x|}}{2x}\\
&=&
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{2x^2+2x|\sin x|}\\
&=&
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{2+2\frac{|\sin x|}{x}}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}